# Exception when using LINQ orderby: "Failed to compare two elements in the array"

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Here is sample code to reproduce the exception:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Demo
{
    [Keyless]
    public class Contact
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
        public string? Address { get; set; } = default!;
        public int? CCode { get; set; } = 0;
        public int OtherValue { get; set; } = 0;
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<Contact> raw = new();
            raw.Add(new Contact { CCode = 1, Name = "Foo", Address = "Bar" });
            raw.Add(new Contact { CCode = 2, Name = "Foo", Address = "Bar" });
            ProcessRawResults(raw);
        }
        public static void ProcessRawResults(List<Contact> raw)
        {
            var q = from i in raw
                    group i by new { i.CCode, i.Name, i.Address } into g
                    orderby g.Key
                    select g;

            foreach (var group in q)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When executing this program, an exception is thrown when execution reaches `foreach (var group in q)`:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Failed to compare two elements in the array.'
>
> Inner Exception
>
> ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable

I have looked at other SO questions about this error message occurring when trying to Sort a List; but in this code I'm not sure which operation needs the comparator. It seems like the `orderby g.Key` operation might need to compare the anonymous class in the group, but then shouldn't the anon class have a default comparator? Or if it doesn't, I'm not sure where to put the code to implement this.

Confusingly, if I take `i.CCode` out of the `group i by new` line, then the exception doesn't happen any more.

---

*Background:* My real project is a Blazor app using EFCore 6 , and am receiving a `List<Contact>` from a Stored Procedure result, so it has to be `[Keyless]`.  I have to work with the existing Stored Procedure unmodified, so am performing a transformation of the result in my code.  I hope to collapse the set of results so that all entries with the same (CCode, Name, Address) result in a single row, and I'll concatenate the OtherValue into a list within that single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's because `int?` is actually `Nullable<int>` and `Nullable<T>` doesn't implement `IComparable`. I just tested your code but changed the grouping to this:

```cs
group i by new { CCode = i.CCode.HasValue ? i.CCode.Value : (int?)null, i.Name, i.Address } into g
```

and it seemed to work. It didn't throw that exception, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous type do not have comparator, specify oder by properties:

```cs
var q = from i in raw
        group i by new { i.CCode, i.Name, i.Address } into g
        orderby g.Key.CCode, g.Key.Name, g.Key.Address 
        select g;
```